# Динамичное поле в Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

Как правильно вместо поля подставить параметр в Room? делаю так:

```
@Query("SELECT *  FROM ActivityObject WHERE :field Like :value ORDER BY ActivityObject.uuid")
    override fun getFilteredData(field: String, value: String): LiveData<List<ActivityObject>>
```

,где `:field` динамическое поле, но данные не возвращаются, как можно отладить этот момент?

Comment: Похоже, что такое не поддерживается либой. Однако можно юзать [RawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery), которые из обычной строки собираются. Туда, по идее, можно что угодно вставить. Будет костыльно и без проверок компилятором, но работать должно.

Comment: В Котлине ведь есть плейсхолдеры или как их там называют - это здесь не прокатит? Типа так: `... WHERE $field ...`